# PHP: How to update one column based on multiple ID using whereIn clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html, laravel

My sample array named "number"
['One', 'Two', 'Three']

User ID's -> 1 2 3

I have a checkbox that has a value = "{{ $number }} - {{ $user->RowID }}" and a name = "number[]"

I have looped these values in my blade template.

Now the problem is that how am i going to update one column which is the number based on multiple user id's.

I tried imploding the $number array like this:

$variable = implode(", ", $number)

I can only update one cell in the "number" column like this:

One - 1, Two - 2, Three - 3

My Model Code:

```
    $numberArr = $request->input('number');
    $numbers = implode(", ", $numberArr);
    $this->number = $numbers;
    $this->update();
```

Now what i needed is update the column "number" based on the user id and seperate the value based on their " - ID" . For example.

The "Number" is the column.

Row 1:

RowID: 1 , Number: One

Row 2:

RowID: 2 , Number: Two

Row 3:

RowID: 3 , Number: Three

Comment: can you show a sample data in your table with before and after update data

Comment: | RowID | | Number |
      1            One

      2            Two

      3            Three

@Capt.Teemo

Comment: means you want to update data like user_id= 1   number= one,user_id=2 number=two, user_id=3 number=3

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreach loop to update records as below

```
  foreach($array as $a){               
    $demo = MODEL::where('id', $a['user_id'])->update(['number' => $a['number']]);
   }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the user id is on a different array. They are not on the same array.

Comment: What i did in my latest code is that i used substr function. 


           $number =  [" One - 2 "];

           $result = substr($number, -2);


How can i use the $result variable as a basis?